# Cannot Fetch OAuth Access Token in Postman

Tags: authentication, oauth, postman

I cannot fetch the OAuth access token using postman. If I pass the Body as "x-www-form-urlencoded" then I could fetch the token. But if I send the body as raw text, I am receiving an error. By the way I am not passing anything under headers.

Comment: What version of Postman is that, seems very old.

Comment: I am using the postman version "Current Version: v6.0.10"

Comment: Yikes - Just about to release 7.22.0